# Displaying users in a group (Linux)

Tags: linux

Is there any way to display the users in a particular group in linux?

I've tried a couple of different things and everything I've found on the web so far hasn't been relative to what I need.

Comment: Then it helps if you show what you've already tried and why it doesn't solve your actual problem. Because Linux systems can be configured to use many different sources of identity information and addressing some may indeed require particular care.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer:

```
$ getent group | grep groupname
```

The advantage this has over reading `/etc/group` directly is that it will include non-local groups. For instance, if your system is AD-bound or is using LDAP for authentication, `getent` will list those groups and their members as well.

Comment: Why the gratuitous `grep`? You can just do `getent group groupname`!

Comment: Haha, old habits die hard. And I don't want poor old `grep` to feel un-loved and un-used.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep '^groupname:' /etc/group | cut -f4 -d:
```

The file `/etc/group` lists what users are in a group. Strictly speaking this shows what users have this group as an additional group, but usually the user is also added to the primary group's list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use members command, just:

```
$ members groupname
```